# Unit test additional output

Tags: c#, unit-testing, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Is there any way how I can output more information in a Windows Store App Unit Test?

I'd like to write some information that are not critical but good to know like the execution time of a specific function call to the console.

Unfortunately I can't find anything on this topic.
There is no Console class so I can't use Console.WriteLine(...);. Debug.WriteLine(...); doesn't seem to produce output.

Writing the data to a file would probably work but I'd prefer not to do that.

Comment: Where do you want to write the data, if not in a file? If I get you right you'd like to use Console but ehre is none, is that right? Have you looked to enabling console in a Windows Store App?

Comment: Well there are multiple output "consoles" (i.e. Debug/Tests/etc.), writing to any of them would do the job.
No I haven't, are you sure that that's possible?

Comment: what about Trace.WriteLine(...);

Comment: Doesn't seem to be available.

Comment: Yes, I mean't Debug.WriteLine. Okay you were faster :)